# How do vpn providers prevent other user internal ip access?

Tags: vpn

For example, `user1` and `user2` use some public VPN provider like proton/nord or so on. `User1` has internal IP `10.96.0.4` and `user2` has `10.96.0.10`. How do a vpn provider prevent `user1` from scanning `user2` internal IP?

Comment: Because they are completely different networks?

Comment: @schroeder `10.96.0.4  and 10.96.0.10` in the same network

Comment: By the same mechanism as all other network flow controls: firewall it?

Comment: Are they? Is user1 using the same network infrastructure as user2? Are they in the same building? In the same coffee shop etc.? And if  they are, do they share the same virtual network to connect to the VPN? Or does each VPN connection to each user create a different connection that uses a different IP to the VPN?

Comment: @schroeder check the answer of Steffen Ullrich it is answering my question. p.s. Asking 6 questions in one comment doesn't look like an attempt to help, you are supposed to moderate this place instead of pushing users to fruitless discussions

Comment: These are your details you are providing. I'm asking for clarification. Steffan's answer is wrong depending on what you mean.

Comment: @GhostRider, it’s generally a bad idea to tell mods what they should and shouldn’t do.  Better to ask them why they do a specific thing. Most often, what seems fruitless to you is in fact trying to help you to give the context needed to properly anwser your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that this question is about the common case of consumer VPN where user1 and user2 are different users of the VPN service, i.e. each client systems creates their own VPN tunnel and that 10.96.0.4 and 10.96.0.10 are the local IP addresses they get assigned for the VPN tunnel. This is explicitly not about the case were user1 and user2 are sharing the same local network with a shared VPN gateway and a single VPN user account (typically on some router or firewall).

These are internal IP addresses only, i.e. not routable on the internet. There can be many networks which us these IP addresses. Even if this is the same network the connectivity between these addresses is fully in control of the VPN provider, i.e. there is no direct connection possible bypassing the VPN provider.

Or in pictures: it is not like this where clients can talk directly to each other outside of the VPN:

[image: false: clients can talk directly to each other]

But like this, where clients connect to the VPN provider and any traffic between the clients is regulated by the VPN provider:

[image: true: clients talk only to VPN provider which controls connectivity between clients]

It is unlikely that the VPN provider allows any connection between these addresses (simple traffic policies/firewall). Note also that this is not specific to VPN but also to [CG-NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) which is heavily used today due to the shortage of IPv4 addresses.

Comment: But this is only true if the traffic goes through the VPN first. If the 2 nodes are on the same local network, the traffic from one might not be routed through the VPN connection. If the VPN is not the default gateway, then traffic can flow to the local network without going through the VPN.

Comment: @schroeder: Correct, this is assuming that each system runs their own VPN client and that there is not a central VPN gateway for multiple clients (i.e. not something on the router of the internal network). This seems to be the scenario the OP is asking about.

Comment: even with one's own VPN client, you can have a different local gateway.

Answer (score -1):

### Case #1: 10.96.0.4 is the local network IP

IP `10.96.0.4` is what the local network gives you. When you connect to the VPN, a new network device is created with a new IP given by the VPN. But details matter before we can answer your question:

- if all traffic goes to the VPN, then the VPN has no knowledge of the route to `10.96.0.0/24` since that's not the VPN's network; therefore no scanning to a `10.96.0.0/24` IP.
- if only internet traffic goes to the VPN, then all local traffic can go to the local network - so if the other node is on the same physical network, then scanning can still happen because the VPN isn't involved
- if nodes use IPs from the same subnet range (e.g. `10.96.0.0/24`) but are on different networks, then the question is moot because the VPN only deals with the IP it gives you; the local IP assignment doesn't matter, and since they are on different networks, there is no way to scan; the VPN isn't involved in blocking it and the entire Internet is in the way.

### Case #2: 10.96.0.4 is the VPN-assigned IP

If, however, you're asking the case where the VPN is giving the IP `10.96.0.4`, then it's a simple a matter of routing rules internally to the VPN network to only allow traffic out to the gateway and not internally.

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/536577/how-does-a-vpn-manage-local-ip-addresses

Comment: I am missing the whole subnet dimension in @Ghost Rider his question. Something we would need to even start guessing what topology is being used. 

Also, VLAN is a thing, which could add more network segregation into the mix. And all of that is without looking at firewalls which actively controls traffic on networks, typically. 

Still. Essentially you and Steffen gave correct awnsers… if not complete. (In my view this isn’t a security question at all. But a network one).

Comment: I completely agree on all your points. My point is that the local network has its own controls, which are separate from the VPNs, and the control over those controls depends on context.